# Background EAGLContext - Recycle or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am doing background texture loading in OpenGL ES (iOS).

Basically, every time I want to load a texture, I run the following block, asynchronously, in a background thread (using GCD):

1. Read image data from file
2. Create EAGLContext with same `API` and `shareGroup` as main rendering context.
3. Generate texture, configure etc.
4. Flush.

My question is: Should I create a new background context every time (like above), or is it better to have a single, "dedicated" background context and reuse it? How expensive is it to create/destroy OpenGL ES contexts?

Comment: Creating contexts is a heavy weight operation. I certainly would reuse them if possible. Of course the answer for all performance questions is that you should measure it. :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have an opportunity to measure it yet. I was refactoring my old code from a "reuse contexts" design to a more "create on demand one", but haven't tried it on resource-heavy examples yet (e.g. 1 texture only).

Comment: I'll stick to the old design, just to be safe.